# disable compression options in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I run mongodb community edition in version 3.0 on Linux Redhat 6.
I would like to disable compression option to improve performance.

My config file is:

```
systemLog:
   destination: file
   path: /var/log/mongodb/domains/Instruments/INS_UNIV_univ_DBIZ/mongod.log
   logAppend: true
storage:
   dbPath: "/export/mongodb/domains/Instruments/INS_UNIV_univ_DBIZ/data"
   engine: wiredTiger
   wiredTiger:
      collectionConfig:
         blockCompressor: none
processManagement:
   fork: true
   pidFilePath: /var/run/mongodb/mongod-ins.pid
net:
   port: 5865
replication:
   replSetName: MONGO_INS_UNIV_univ_DBIZ
security:
   keyFile: /etc/keyfile-ins.txt
setParameter:
   enableLocalhostAuthBypass: false
```

This config file works well and the mongo server starts normally but if I add the option index prefix compression, the server does not start any more.

```
systemLog:
   destination: file
   path: /var/log/mongodb/domains/Instruments/INS_UNIV_univ_DBIZ/mongod.log
   logAppend: true
storage:
   dbPath: "/export/mongodb/domains/Instruments/INS_UNIV_univ_DBIZ/data"
   engine: wiredTiger
   wiredTiger:
      collectionConfig:
         blockCompressor: none
      indexConfig:
         prefixCompression: none
processManagement:
   fork: true
   pidFilePath: /var/run/mongodb/mongod-ins.pid
net:
   port: 5865
replication:
   replSetName: MONGO_INS_UNIV_univ_DBIZ
security:
   keyFile: /etc/keyfile-ins.txt
setParameter:
   enableLocalhostAuthBypass: false
```

Any help will be very appreciate

Answer (score 2):

That should be

```
indexConfig:
     prefixCompression: false
```

Instead of

```
indexConfig:
     prefixCompression: none
```

As the property is Boolean, not a string